# Selectively Support Certain Browsers

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

Ok everyone, I have a requirement to only support IE 11+, Chrome 31+, etc. The specifics don't really matter at this point. I know it's not ideal to restrict other browsers, but this is a vendor requirement and isn't my call. I'm just trying to figure out how to go about doing this.

Initially I wanted to use feature detection (my assumption was that the site needed to be HTML5 compatible). These requirements have changed. Is feature detection still viable for this? I would prefer to not use user agent sniffing, since it's so easy to spoof.

I'm using ASP.NET, C#, .NET 4.0, jQuery, HTML5, CSS3

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you hate your users?

Comment: @MarcGravell not me. Remember, 3rd party vendor requirement. I can't speculate as to their position about their users. :)

Comment: Theres a difference between supporting browsers and restricting access from browsers.. do you want the latter?

Comment: If you downvote, can you please elaborate why? If it's something wrong with the format of my question, or not enough information, please let me know. If it's because I have a requirement to only support certain browsers, please don't downvote me because I have to support something stupid.

Comment: Yes, I've been told it's a hard restriction. No fallbacks or HTML5 compatibility libraries, unfortunately.

Comment: Quit the project and work for someone else. Any company that backwards thinking is bound for failure.

Comment: Again, this isn't my company, this is a 3rd party vendor that has this requirement. Even if my company wanted to pull out at this point, it would be pointless as we are a few months away from go-live on a project that's spanned around 2 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look inside the Request server variable for useful information about the browser. While debugging, it looks to me like this is getting generated from the user agent. From what I know about the web though, this is how clients communicate to servers what they are capable of viewing.

There are a few properties that can help you within Request.Browser.

```
Request.Browser.Type //Returns "Chrome41"
Request.Browser.Browser // Returns "Chrome"
```

You could also use conditional comments for IE, something like this:

```
<!--[if IE 11]>
(Redirect users here or however you want to handle it)
<![endif]-->
```

I'm sure you've seen these before, but that statement basically is targeting any IE version less than 11. These are Microsoft / IE specific so while this will help you with your IE issue, you will most likely have to rely on the user agent or `Request` as above for other browsers.

Comment: [This](http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/) blog states that support for conditional comments was removed in IE 10. I had thought about conditional comments, but was looking for another way due to this fact.